# How to cache wordpress theme images?

Tags: css, image, wordpress, caching

i would like to cache wordpress theme images, but i dont know how to do it :)

Comment: Google can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send 'Expires' headers with the images. This is really something the server does not WordPress specifically. You want something like this, which is what I use, in your .htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 weeks"
</FilesMatch>
```

I am assuming that you are on an Apache server and have [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) installed.

See: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-far-future-expires-headers-to-your-wordpress-site-1533